# PHP Fatal error: Your PHP version must be equal or higher than 5.6.0 to use CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0, centos6, cake-bake

I am running a self-administrated 1and1 dedicated server:

`CentOS 6.10 (Final)
 Linux 2.6.32-504.30.3.el6.x86_64`

and getting the following error: "PHP Fatal error: Your PHP version must be equal or higher than 5.6.0 to use CakePHP". My initial thought is I have missed setting the path for PHP somewhere. I have tried checking/changing the following things, and I'm not sure what else to try.

`phpinfo()` shows:

> PHP Version 7.3.7

`php -v` shows:

> PHP 7.3.7 (cli) (built: Jul  5 2019 12:52:53) ( NTS )

`bin/cake` produces:

> PHP Fatal error:  Your PHP version must be equal or higher than 5.6.0
>   to use CakePHP.

Removing from requirements.php:

```
if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.6.0') < 0) {
     trigger_error('Your PHP version must be equal or higher than 5.6.0 to use CakePHP.' . PHP_EOL, E_USER_ERROR);
 }
```

`bin/cake` again after that line removed:

> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'DateTimeImmutable' not found in
>   /var/www/vhosts/xxxxxxxxxx.com/app/vendor/cakephp/chronos/src/Chronos.php
>   on line 50

`which php` shows:

> alias php='/opt/plesk/php/7.3/bin/php'    /opt/plesk/php/7.3/bin/php

Comment: Check `phpinfo()` from inside a web page. The version of PHP you're running from the command line may not be the same as what your web server is running.

Comment: src/Template/Pages/home.ctp. Shows Your version of PHP is 5.6.0 or higher (detected 7.3.7) and echo phpinfo() shows PHP Version 7.3.7

Comment: So, it says that your version of PHP is 5.6.0 or higher, but also gives a fatal error that it must be 5.6.0 or higher to run?

Comment: Just to clarify.  Currently only failing when I try to bake.  Still working with the default  install from "php composer.phar create-project --prefer-dist cakephp/app".  It did install without any errors.
Everywhere I check shows PHP Version 7.3.7.  Both on the cli and html (phpinfo) pages.  It is only when I try to bake that I get the error.  It's like bake is looking in some obscure place for the PHP version.

Comment: Bake is just code, you can look at it and debug it. You ran `composer install` after the initial `create-project`, yes?

Comment: I did not run composer install after creating the project with composer.  When I ran composer install, it failed because of the php version being to low.  I looked at bake.php and commented out the requirments section.  bake then throws the error PHP Fatal error:  Class 'DateTimeImmutable' not found

Comment: I edited src/Template/Pages/home.ctp and changed how it is checking for the php version to match requirements.php (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.6.0', '>=')) vs (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.6.0' < 0)) and now the home page indicates the php version is to low.  I am now going to focus on how PHP_VERSION is checking.  Thanks for your help so far.  I am just trying to follow the Content Management Tutorial

Comment: You've changed it to trigger the error message about version being to low when the version is greater than or equal to 5.6.0? That code was right before. I can't tell yet where your actual problem is, but if you can't run `composer install`, then that's going to lead to all kinds of other problems.

Comment: This is a server problem.  My solution was to switch to a single php version server.  Not sure how to mark this question as closed so people don't waste any time